One frame is rendered for 15 frames then next
I am new to Blender but going nuts. I am rendering a simple model (created in sketchup), where a pack is rotating 180 degrees in 125 frames (25 fps, 5 seconds).
I have rendered a few of them. Some of them render fine.
But in some files, one frame is repeated 15 times, then the next frame is rendered. The end resulting first and last frames are correct, but the movement is definitely not usable.
My frame step value is set to 1. My Keyframe interval is set to 15. I tried setting to it 1 and rendering a low res, but still the same problem persists.
What should I look out for?

What is a keyframe interval?

Hate to go for this right out of the gate, but this might be a “share your file“ situation. The recommended method is blend-exchange.com

Here it is:  

You’re supposed to edit that into the question, but that’ll do.
